# The volume of a sphere?

Tags: python

The volume of a sphere with radius r is 4/3 π r3. What is the volume of a sphere with radius 5? Hint: 392.6 is wrong!

```
print (((4/3.0) * 3.14) * 5**3)
```

It gave me this

```
523.333333333
```

what's wrong???

python 2.7

Comment: `392.7` is what you would get if you'd used `4/3` instead of `4/3.0` in Python 2.7 because `4/3` would become 1.  Probably that's what the question was warning you about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, you have the correct answer. You may want to use `math.pi` instead of 3.14 however to increase precision of your answer.

```
>>> from __future__ import division # not necessary if using python 3
>>> 4/3*math.pi*5**3
523.59877559829886
```

See the solution at [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume%20of%20a%20sphere%20radius%205)

If you use floor division instead of true division you will get 392.6, which is what the hint was getting at:

```
>>> 4//3*math.pi*5**3
392.69908169872411
```

Comment: Floor division == integer division.  Instead of 4/3 ≈ 1.333, you'd get 1.

Comment: @BassamBadr in python 2 the division operator (`/`) and in python 2 and 3 the floor division operator (`//`) perform floor division. The result of floor division is equal to calling `floor()` on the true division answer. The result is the greatest integer that is less than or equal to, the true division result.

Answer (score 0):

For those working with version 3:
Simple print statement works as a charm.

```
print((4/3)*(22/7)*5**3)
```

output : 523.8095238095237